# Error message "cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'bean-discovery-mode' must appear on element 'beans'."

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

I have a simple Java EE project and under WEB-INF there is a simple beans.xml. It basically contains nothing. But I always got this error message "cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'bean-discovery-mode' must appear on element 'beans'." indicated for the line "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd" in JBoss Developer Studio.

What does this message mean? I googled but found nothing. What might cause this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Marker file indicating CDI should be enabled -->
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment this alternative to see EJB declarative transactions in 
        use -->
    <!-- <alternatives> -->
        <!-- <class>org.jboss.as.quickstarts.greeter.domain.EJBUserDao</class> -->
    <!-- </alternatives> -->
</beans>
```

Comment: Is this error appearing only in your IDE or is it in your app server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message clearly says the attribute `bean-discovery-mode` should be there in element `beans`, this may be a requirement of your container. Try giving the attribute to bean element as follows:

```
bean-discovery-mode = "annotated"
```

The reason is you are using CDI 1.1, and therefore `bean-discovery-mode` is a compulsory attribute. You may confirm it by reading the XSD file available from the following URL:

`http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd`.

Note the following portion in particular:

```
<xs:attribute name="bean-discovery-mode" use="required">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>
                   It is strongly recommended you use "annotated". 

                   If the bean discovery mode is "all", then all types in this
                   archive will be considered. If the bean discovery mode is
                   "annotated", then only those types with bean defining annotations will be
                   considered. If the bean discovery mode is "none", then no
                   types will be considered.
                </xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
```

Comment: Yes, That work. But this example comes with Jboss Wildfly Quickstart projects. I suppose it should work without any modification. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: The example may have been written for CDI 1.0, and you seem to be using CDI 1.1. See my updated answer.